# Django views is it possible to select only the first four elements for a specific model.item?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a profile model that is displaying various items. 
One of those is the country attached to the profile.

Here is what happen in the view:

```
class ProfilePartnerListView(FormMixin, BaseProfilePartnerView, ListView):
    model = ProfilePartner
    context_object_name = 'profile_list'
    view_url_name = 'djangocms_partner_profile:profile-list'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      context = {}

      self.object_list = self.get_queryset().order_by('-date_created')

      context.update(self.get_context_data(**kwargs))
      context[self.context_object_name] = context['object_list']

      country_for_articles = Country.objects.exclude(regions_partner_profile=None).order_by('name')
      industries_qs = ProfilePartnerIndustry.objects.active_translations(
        get_language()).order_by('translations__name')
      budget_qs = ProfilePartner.objects.values_list('budget',
                                                        flat=True).distinct()

      context['load_more_url'] = self.get_load_more_url(request, context)


      context['regions_list'] = country_for_articles
      context['industry_list'] = industries_qs
      context['budget_list'] = budget_qs

      return self.render_to_response(context)
```

I know, for example 'regions_list', how to return only 4 elements from it.
But the thing is, my main object 'profile_list' that I use in the template for the rendering, is displaying all the country of the item when I do:

```
{% for profile in profile_list %}
    {% for country in profile.regions.all %}
        <div class="col-xs-12">{{ country }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

And some of the profiles got 5 or 6 country. I want to only display the first 4.
Is there a way of doing it?

Many thanks!

ps: `region_list`, `industry_list` and `budget_list` are use for categories, it has nothing to do with what I want here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) filter for this:

```
{% for profile in profile_list %}
    {% for country in profile.regions.all|slice:":4" %}
        <div class="col-xs-12">{{ country }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: When you use slice, if I call `{% forloop.last %}` will it be the fourth element as-well ?

Comment: I am glad to help. Please accept the answer if it solves your query.

Comment: Time limitation ;) I will do as soon as I reach the time limite.